# CSS is not getting applied on full body

Tags: html, sass

I am trying to use the blur effect on full `body` then I have section for `navbar` but the css applies effect on the remaining section only

```
<body>
    <main>
        <section class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>News feed</li>
                <li>Trending</li>
                <li>History</li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
```

** CSS code**:

```
@mixin glass{
    background: rgba(66, 66, 68, 0.4);
    backdrop-filter: blur(3rem);
}

main{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    @include glass();

    .navbar{
        max-width: 120px;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

To display output, I have attached the screenshot where the left side is `navbar` section that covers 120px and the bigger greyed out part is the remaining section

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b3Hx.png)

Comment: https://jsbin.com/peqawikeka/1/edit?css,output — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: but on my system its still doing this @Quentin I am using vscode and chrome

Comment: Either (a) the code you provided is not responsible for the problem and you need to provide a [mcve] or (b) the problem is with a specific browser (in which case you should test in multiple browsers and update the question to say which ones work nd which do not) or (c) something is broken on your system and this is a problem for superuser, not stackoverflow.

Comment: I resolved it!! I actually had put `background-image: url('./images/bg.jpg');` in the root section `*{ background-image: url('./images/bg.jpg'); }', bringing that down to main section fixed it. Although I did not understand the logic but yeah its fixed.

Thanks @Quentin for your time